# How to format a big number with different bigmarks for thousand and millions (i.e. 1'000,000) in R

Tags: r, formatting

Some countries use apostrophes `"'"` as million marks, and commas `","` for thousand marks as in `1'234,567`. Is there a way to custom format numbers to do so?

I have only found answers that [round numbers and add some letters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57576031/12425067) as in `1.3B`, or [deal with this issue in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61162801/12425067), which I don't speak.

`Format` and `prettyNum` documentation seem to have only a `big.mark` argument with no option to set different ones within the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write my own function to do that, check the logic here.

```r
custom_format <- function(number, msep = "'", tsep = ",") {
  number = format(number, scientific = FALSE)
  
  dplyr::case_when(
    # for millions
    nchar(number) <= 9 & nchar(number) > 6 ~
      stringr::str_replace(
        number,
        "([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})$",
        paste0("\\1", msep, "\\2", tsep, "\\3")
      ),
    nchar(number) <= 6 & nchar(number) > 3 ~
      stringr::str_replace(
        number, 
        "([0-9])([0-9]{3})$", 
        paste0("\\1", tsep, "\\2")
      ),
    nchar(number) <= 3 ~ number,
    # For Thousands
    TRUE ~ number
  )
}

number <- c(10, 1500, 1000, 1000000, 23000, 234000000)
purrr::map_chr(number, custom_format)
#> [1] "10"          "1,500"       "1,000"       "1'000,000"   "23,000"     
#> [6] "234'000,000"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I just found  it fails when having zeroes right after the marks eg.:
> custom_format(c(1234034, 1034234, 12005006))
[1] "1'234,34" "1'34,234" "12'5,6"

Comment: Oh, it's true. Sorry for that, I will fix it!!

Comment: I added a new solution, but this time the funcion is not vectorized. Anyway, I'll try to add a better solution later.